# send twitter status with geolcation using api

Tags: android, twitter

i have integrated twitter API in my android application using twitter4j API and i want to sent status with geolocation and for that i used this method

```
    public void updateStatus(String status,GeoLocation geo) throws Exception {
    try {
        mTwitter.updateStatus(status,geo);
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

and also  the geo have

```
     geo=new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
```

in result the mesage is posted but with no view location in the twit so can anyone help me
to add  my geo location to the twit status
thx for replay

Comment: Did you see "from 'your-location'" at the bottom of the message?

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood. But if the message has location info, then the code works?

Comment: i didnt got u but the message get posted but with no view location under it

Comment: @steevoo : first check this api is supported or not on ur device by using `if (Geolocation.isSupported)` maybe possible..

Answer (score 0):

Concat geo location with your status

```
mTwitter.updateStatus(status + ": " + geo);
```